# Why dont my Shift keys work the same in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

SO i have this weird Problem where I cant delete a line in VSCode with Ctrl + Shift + K. I only figured out that its the case with my left Ctrl, but when I use the right one it works completely fine.On my laptop I have Win10 and the same Keyboard and it works normally.
When i go into Keyboard Shortcuts in VSC and record keys, it only registers ctrl and shift but doesnt record the K, all other letters are fine. The right Shift works normally.
Why isnt it working?

OS: Win11
Keyboard lang: German QWERTZ

Help

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.